# Pyspark - Convert column to list

Tags: python, pyspark

Spark 3.0

I ran a code `df.select("Name").collect()`, and I received this output below. I want to put the result below in a list. I tried adding [0] to the end, but that didn't work.

```
Row(Name='Andy')
Row(Name='Brandon')
Row(Name='Carl')

expected outcome = ['Andy','Brandon','Carl']
```

Comment: You could simply run : 
         expected_outcome = [a["Name"] for a in df.select("Name").collect() ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`collect_list`** then get only the list by accessing index and assigned to variable.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------+
#|   Name|
#+-------+
#|   Andy|
#|Brandon|
#|   Carl|
#+-------+

output=df.agg(collect_list(col("name"))).collect()[0][0]

output
#['Andy', 'Brandon', 'Carl']
```

Another way would be using **list comprehension**:

```
ss=df.select("Name").collect()

output=[i[0] for i in ss]

output
#['Andy', 'Brandon', 'Carl']
```

Comment: `collect_list` worked fine for me

Answer (score 6):

You can use rdd.

```
df.select('Name').rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()

['Andy', 'Brandon', 'Carl']
```